# How to match a number in the middle using regular expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex

For example:

```
start 2 4 9

end 5 8 39
```

How to match 4 and 8 using regular expression?
Thanks!

Comment: Always 3 numbers? Any decimal points? Anything else we should know?

Comment: Also why are do you need to use regex? Why not split at every a-zA-Z... and then split each by spaces? Ex 1 2 3 abc 4 5 6 def 7 8 9 -> 1 2 3, abc 4 5 6, def 7 8 9. Then split each by spaces, the first case will be the 2nd element, the others the middle number will be the 3rd element. If you want me to elaborate I can do so below. Just asking to clarify why regex?

Comment: Yes, always 3 numbers and every kind of number is possible.

Comment: I want to use regex because I want to do some practice. Split is a good method, just curious of how to do it using regular expression.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non regex solution I commented above. This is in pseudocode, if the idea holds true this can easily be cross applied to Java.

My comment:

> Also why are do you need to use regex? Why not split at every
>   a-zA-Z... and then split each by spaces? Ex 1 2 3 abc 4 5 6 def 7 8 9
>   -> 1 2 3, abc 4 5 6, def 7 8 9. Then split each by spaces, the first case will be the 2nd element, the others the middle number will be the
>   3rd element. If you want me to elaborate I can do so below. Just
>   asking to clarify why regex?

The pseudo coded example:

```
theString = "1 2 3 abc 4 5 6 def 7 8 9"
theString = theString.toLower() //lower case for ease of matching
splitS = theString.split([a-Z])
middleNum=[]
middleNum.add(splitS[0][1]) //the 2nd element of the 1st element in the array.
for int i =1; i<splitS.len; i++){
    middleNum.add(splitS[i][2])
}
return middleNum //the middle numbers
// or you can stringily it and return a string vs. array.
```

// let me know if this is what you are trying to use regex for. Regex won't necessarily make this problem any easier. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't see a great increase in efficiency vs. splitting it because there is a lot of forwards / backwards checking to handle due to it being the 2nd number and split by non-numerical characters.

This also allows you to change your desired output more easily. For example if you want to change to  the next number because the number string is now 4 chars it's easy to understand what you're doing. I'm assuming you're relatively new to java if you're working on splitting strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I am new to java so I need more practice. I'll try this. Thank you!

Comment: @Wenchao if this has helped you could you accept my answer? Thank you

Comment: There is something I don't get in your pseudo-code, `splitS` is a one-dimensional array, what is `splitS[0][1]` ?

Comment: @Volune SplitS[0] is the array of split strings ex abc 123 are 2, [1] is the 2nd character in the string. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Ex abc[1] = b

Comment: @TaiHirabayashi I think you wanted `splitS[0].split(" ")[1]` instead of `splitS[0][1]`. Also you'll want to test if `splitS[N]` is not an empty string. You may have empty strings between letters, or an empty string at the beginning if theString starts with a word (like `start 2 4 9`). I wrote [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrezeeoL/1/) to show these points.

Comment: @Volune I intended the above example to be pseudocode, and in some languages strings are essentially the same as arrays. I can call myString[x] to get that character. But I see your point that may be hard for someone to understand. There is no assumption of spaces between the chars so split(" ") would not work I believe. The original example was a string without spaces ex "abc" followed by a number string "123" But after seeing the question edited then my assumptions no longer hold true. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

Solution with regexp, `\\d+` matches a number, `\\s+` matches spaces between numbers, `(\\d+)` parenthesis capture middle number.

```
public static Integer extractMiddleNumber(String source) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\\d+").matcher(source);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return null; //not found, you can throw exception if you prefer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only three numbers present for each line, you could use the below regex which captures and stores the second number into group 1.

```
^\D*\d+\D*(\d+)\D*\d+\D*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wG4jR8/3)

**Example:**

```
String s = "start 2 4 9";
Pattern regex1 = Pattern.compile("^\\D*\\d+\\D*(\\d+)\\D*\\d+\\D*$");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex1.matcher(s);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
String ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
System.out.println(ResultString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this way

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/*
 * thanks http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=start%202%204%209&-1&9&3&10&4&11&5
 */
public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] txt = { "start 2 4 9", "end 5 8 39" };
        for (String s : txt) {
            match(s);
        }
    }

    private static void match(String txt) {
        String re1 = "(start|end)"; // Word 1
        String re2 = "(\\s+)"; // White Space 1
        String re3 = "(\\d+)"; // Integer Number 1
        String re4 = "(\\s+)"; // White Space 2
        String re5 = "(\\d+)"; // Integer Number 2 <==========
        String re6 = "(\\s+)"; // White Space 3
        String re7 = "(\\d+)"; // Integer Number 3

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + re6 + re7,
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
        if (m.find()) {
            // String word1=m.group(1);
            // String ws1=m.group(2);
            // String int1=m.group(3);
            // String ws2=m.group(4);
            String int2 = m.group(5);
            // String ws3=m.group(6);
            // String int3=m.group(7);
            System.out.println(int2);
        }
    }
}
```